# Arrow function should not return assignment when using axios to get api data (Vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

So I'm trying to get data from an URL using Axios in my vue app but it keeps returning the following error:
`Arrow function should not return assignment`

Full error output:

```
error: Arrow function should not return assignment (no-return-assign) at src\components\navbar.vue:123:13:
  121 |   created() {
  122 |     axios.get('http://ip-api.com/json')
> 123 |       .then((response) => (this.countryCode = response.countryCode));
      |             ^
  124 |   },
  125 | };
  126 | </script>


1 error found.
```

My code:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'navbarr',
  data() {
    return {
      countryCode: null,
      country: '',
      countries: [
        { value: 'INT' },
        { value: 'UK' },
        { value: 'PT' },
        { value: 'US' },
        { value: 'FR' },
        { value: 'DE' },
        { value: 'IT' },
        { value: 'ES' },
        { value: 'IE' },
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('http://ip-api.com/json')
      .then((response) => (this.countryCode = response.countryCode));
  },
};
</script>
```

I was following the official examples and I can't understand what's wrong here!

Comment: Have you try to enclose function body in brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) violation. The solution is to use braces to indicate that your arrow function doesn't actually have a return value

```js
.then((response) => {
  this.countryCode = response.countryCode
})
```

Another option is to set the [`except-parens`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign#options) option in your ESLint config.

Comment: Phil the legend!